# Problema con la condicional while script ubuntu

Tags: bash

Hice unas pruebas en otro archivo para realizar este código que al final me funciono, pero cuando le pido otro valor no hace caso de a condición del while.
Quiero que el usuario siga creado usuarios en caso de que diga 'y' o x valor, pero en caso de que diga 'n' debería parar el código.
Este es el código que tengo creado:

```
read -p "¿Quieres eliminar o crear un usuario?" opcion
case $opcion in
     eliminar)
         while [ "$usu" != "n" ]
            do
                read -p "¿Quieres eliminar un usuario? (y/n) " usu
                pure-pw list | cut -f 1
                read -p "¿Que usuario quieres eliminar? " delet
                pure-pw userdel $delet
            done;;
     crear)
         while [ "$usu" != "n" ]
            do
                read -p "¿Quieres crear un usuario? (y/n) " usu
                read -p "Nombre del nuevo usuario: " nom
                read -p "Nombre del grupo que pertenecerá: " gru
                read -p "Nombre del usuario del sistema al que pertenecerá: " sis
                pure-pw useradd $nom -u $sis -g $gru -d /home/pruebas/$nom -m
            done;;
      *)
           echo "Opción no aceptada";;
esac
```

Es decir, al quitar la petición de la nueva variable me realiza el código sin problemas, pero es que no entiendo por qué lo hace.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte de cada ciclo elimina la condición que pusiste y reemplázalo por los dos puntos (`:`) el cual funciona como un `while True` y pon la siguiente línea después de la pregunta.

```
[[ $usu = n ]] && exit
```

para provocar la finalización del programa si ingresa la letra "n".

Por ejemplo, la parte de eliminar usuarios debería quedarte algo así.

```
while :
do
    read -p "¿quieres eliminar un usuario? (y/n): " usu
    [[ $usu = n ]] && exit
    echo list | cut -f 1
    read -p "¿que usuario quieres eliminar? " delet
    echo userdel $delet
 done;;
```

Aunque el comando `adduser` lo puede hacer de forma interactiva.

Comment: Gracias, simplemente cambie el exit por break para que el código siga su curso ya que la parte que enseñe es solo una opción del menú.